# Integrals to solve Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't need the answer, but can someone tell me how to get this in the integral form:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x + 2xy + xy^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the ODE is separable, as
$$2x+2xy+y^2x=((y+1)^2+1)\cdot x,$$
so you get
$$\frac{y'}{(y+1)^2+1}=x.$$
I guess you know how to proceed from here

Comment: You've missed the $x$ from the first line $2x+2xy+\color{red}{x}y^2=((y+1)^2+1)\cdot x$